# Cucumber Scenario Outline with different buttons

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, gherkin

I want to create a scenario outline that clicks different button on each run. The reason I want to do this is because the buttons yield same expected result, so I can't write multiple Scenarios.

I can't think of a logic to handle this in my head. Below, please see my code.

```
// --- feature file ---
Scenario Outline: click any button other than button1 and display label1
    When i click "<buttontype>"
    Then i am presented with label1
      Examples:
        | buttontype        |
        | button2           |
        | button3           |
        | button4           |

// --- Page Object ---
public class ButtonsObjects {

    public ButtonsObjects(AppiumDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }
    // ------------------ locators ------------------

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "btn1")
    public MobileElement button1;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "btn2")
    public MobileElement button2;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "btn3")
    public MobileElement button3;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "btn4")
    public MobileElement button4;

    // ------------------ actions ------------------
    public void clickButton1() {
      button1.click;
    }

    public void clickButton2() {
      button2.click;
    }

    public void clickButton3() {
      button3.click;
    }

    public void clickButton4() {
      button4.click;
    }

}

// --- step definition ---
@When("^i click \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_click(String arg0) {
        // How do I handle this here?
    }
```

So how do I parameterize these buttons and click them? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Splitting up the code into different blocks would make it easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

What about enriching your PageObject with a method that takes a button name as input and click on the corresponding button?

```java
public void clickOnButton(String buttonName) {
  // Implement as you wish (if/switch/reflection...)
}
```

Then on your Cucumber step, you can just rely on this method:

```java
@When("i click {string}")
public void i_click(String buttonName) {
  pageObject.clickOnButton(buttonName);
}
```

*Note: I used [Cucumber Expressions](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/) for the step annotation which is easier (available since Cucumber 5.x)*

Comment: Hi Gael.

You pointed me to the right direction, I just did a little different. I used the switch statement in the step definition and called the click methods in the case statement.


@When("^i click \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_click(String arg0) {
        try {
            switch(arg0) {
                case "button2":
                     buttonsObjects.clickButton2();
                     break;
               default:
                     log.info(""); 
          } catch(Exception e) {
                     log.info(e.getStackTrace());
              }
    }